# How to improve speediness of automated checking

Tags: java

I am working on Windows automation using the win app driver tool.  I am using java language. My app is commentary related software. It is very data-heavy, so I am using a data driven framework.

I am keeping all the data in an excel sheet and read through the excel file. but when I run my automation my app is very slow. The scenarios I test include things like player selection, game selection, entering commentary events through click actions.

I need to improve the speed of my automated test runs. The only option I have thought of is to keep the data in another memory location.

What can I do to improve the speed of my automation tests?
and click on top menu tab like file menu, view menu, period menu---here start period and end period is there, here selecting the option is getting very very slow

Whether I keep the data in array, and visualize the data is looks same like excel and read the data from array..is it possible to improve speediness of my automated test run.. if not any other solution for this ?

Comment: I really doubt whether reading an excel file is the reason for the slowness. Did you do any experimentation to determine that?

Comment: Why not keep the data in a plain text file with delimiters and read in to an variable at run time?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the performance of test automation scripts depends more on how fast the AUT responds to the client's (in your case client is your test automation script) requests.

When we're talking about GUI (especially if that GUI has asynchronous UI) it takes quite a lot of time to draw all the elements and set the appropriate state in order to let your UI test framework know that the request has been handled and UI is ready for dispatching new events from your client.

So, loading data from file into the memory would not give you additional performance. In your case I would move to the test parallelization direction.

Comment: If I store all the data in array, and visualize that array the data is formatted like excel and read the data. is it possible to improve speediness ? if not any other solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't guess, measure.

Try using a [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) tool to see what exactly causes the performance issues.

As already pointed out by [Alexey](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/35060/21973), your biggest bottleneck is probably the test interface: the GUI. That is, if you can move some data-heavy tests to the API level, that usually boosts the test performance a lot. (And also reduces the maintenance effort.)